# AS3: How to use the "as" operator?

Tags: actionscript-3

```
var o:Object = {title: 'asad'};
var v:ImageItemVO = o as ImageItemVO;
var v:ImageItemVO = ImageItemVO(o); // throws an error
```

my ImageItemVO has a public var named title.
After this code runs the "var v" is null. Why?
Can somebody give me an example of how to make it work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `as` operator is used for casting an object from one type to another, but only works if the object can be casted that way. If it can't it will give you `null`. The other way of casting (the way you do it on the last line), will instead give you an error if the object cannot be casted.

In this case you don't want to cast at all, casting doesn't work that way. Instead, you probably want to do something like this:

```
var v: ImageItemVO = new ImageItemVO();
v.title = "asad";
```

or if there are more properties, and you don't want to type them all by hand:

```
var o: Object = { ... };
var v: ImageItemVO = new ImageItemVO();
for (var key: String in o) {
  v[key] = o[key];
}
```

This code will copy all properties in `o` to `v`.

Comment: so.. there is not anyway to make a ImageItemVO instance with data contained in o?

Comment: Since you're unserializing it from an object -- maybe better to make the method:  ImageItemVO::serialize(o:Object) -- where you can then do the loop this[key] = o[key];