# ActionScript 3 : Why would you omit the new keyword when instantiating a custom eventDispatcher?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, casting

I am currently reading the Actionscript 3 Bible and the author shows an example in which a custom eventDispatcher class is created. When the class is later used in the code it's called as such:

```
//Thermometer is a custom eventDispatcher that extends the eventDispatcher class.
var thermometer:Thermometer = Thermometer(event.target); //why no new keyword?
```

I'm a new programmer and I was curious if someone could explain how this works? Why is the new keyword omitted? When you omit the new keyword on a class that extends another class is it essentially just calling the superclass(eventDispatcher) constructor?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not creating a new instance, but is *casting*.

What that means is that the `target` property of the event object is cast as Object by the Event class, and so to tell the compiler that the target is actually an instance of the Thermometer class, it is cast in this style.  You could also write it like this:

```
var thermometer:Thermometer = event.target as Thermometer;
```

The two essentially mean the same thing, but when using an editor that supports code suggestion/completion for custom objects, the `Class(something)` notation is preferred because it will enable the editor to provide suggestions based on your cast.

Comment: Shane, thanks for the reply. I read up a bit more on casting and it all makes a lot more sense. Very much appreciated. :o)

Comment: Similarly to the "as" operator in C#, the ActionScript3 "as" operator [will give you null if it can't successfully cast your object to your desired type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4108380/as3-how-to-use-the-as-operator).  Code that uses "as" but does not include a null check will almost certainly end up in a bug report later!  Be careful with "as" and don't overuse it.  Casting is powerful but dangerous!  Novice wizards are well advised to apply wisdom when casting spells!

Comment: @John Tobler - I've run across errors occurring because of a null value while casting multiple times now and your comment definitely saved a novice some time. :o)